# Postgres JSON output using specific column as JSON key

Tags: postgresql, json

I have data in Postgres (10.4) in the form of

```
id | my_json
-----------------------------------
1  | {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": [1,2,3]}
2  | {"a": 3, "b": 5, "c": [2,3,4]}
```

I can output the data as JSON like this:

```
WITH l AS (SELECT id, my_json as data FROM table)
SELECT to_json(l) FROM l;
```

and i get:

```
{"id": 1, "data": {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": [1,2,3]}}
{"id": 2, "data": {"a": 3, "b": 5, "c": [2,3,4]}}
```

But is there a way to output the data, keyed by the `id`?

Like this:

```
{"1": {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": [1,2,3]}}
{"2": {"a": 3, "b": 5, "c": [2,3,4]}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [json_build_object](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) function which allows you to calculate keys or values.

```
WITH l AS (SELECT id, my_json as data FROM table)
SELECT json_build_object(id, data) FROM l;
```

The result will be like;

```
|                        json_build_object |
|------------------------------------------|
| {"1" : {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": [1, 2, 3]}} |
| {"2" : {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": [1, 2, 3]}} |
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bbc01/3) is sample fiddle